# Atomic access to non-atomic memory location in C++11 and OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, atomic, nonatomic

OpenMP, in contrast to C++11, works with atomicity from a perspective of memory operations, not variables. That allows, e.g., to use atomic reads/writes for integers being stored in a vector with unknown size at compile time:

```
std::vector<int> v;

// non-atomic access (e.g., in a sequential region):
v.resize(n);
...
v.push_back(i);
...

// atomic access in a multi-threaded region:
#pragma omp atomic write // seq_cst
v[k] = ...;
#pragma omp atomic read // seq_cst
... = v[k];
```

In C++11, this is not possible to achieve. We can kind-of access atomic variables as non-atomic by relaxing memory model, but we cannot resize a vector of atomic elements.

I understand that there are reasons why C++ does not allow to access non-atomic variables by atomic memory operations. But I wonder, why these reasons do not apply for OpenMP as well.

For example, in [N4013](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4013.html), it is said that *"There is no reasonable way to completely portably apply atomic operations to data not declared as atomic."* How it's possible that OpenMP can guarantee such portability and C++ not?

Comment: OpenMP doesn't have to be as portable as C++ and the OpenMP implementers on the language community were fine to allow it. I'll try to lookup details later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the respective standards, OpenMP has more restrictions on usage than C++11, which allows it to be portable without using special types.  For example, OpenMP 4.5 says:

> If the storage location designated by x is not size-aligned (that is, if the byte alignment of x is not a multiple of the size of x), then the behavior of the atomic region is implementation defined.

On the other hand, if C++11 uses `std::atomic<int>`, then the compiler will guarentee the appropriate alignment.  In both cases, alignment is required, but OpenMP and C++11 differ in who is responsible for ensuring this is done.

Generally, there are philosophical differences between OpenMP and C++, but it's hard to enumerate all of them.  The C++ folks are thinking about portability to everything, whereas OpenMP is targeted at HPC.

Comment: "if C++11 uses std::atomic<int>, then the compiler will guarentee the appropriate alignment." - will it? Where does standard forces this?

Comment: If I understand things correctly, C++11 ensures atomicity and does not care about alignment. Whether or not the atomicity depends on the proper alignment is an implementation issue (for a given architecture).

Comment: It's an implementation issue, but if your hardware can only provide atomicity for aligned words, then your C++ compiler is not able to report std::atomic_is_lock_free unless these types are aligned, so it's going to align them.