# Replacing #pragma omp atomic with c++ atomics

Tags: c++11, c++14, openmp, atomic, compare-and-swap

I'm replacing some OpenMP code with standard C++11/C++14 atomics/thread support.  Here is the OpenMP minimal code example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

void omp_atomic_add(std::vector<std::int64_t> const& rows,
                    std::vector<std::int64_t> const& cols,
                    std::vector<double>& values,
                    std::size_t const row,
                    std::size_t const col,
                    double const value)
{
    for (auto i = rows[row]; i < rows[row+1]; ++i)
    {
        if (cols[i] == col)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic
            values[i] += value;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The code updates a CSR matrix format and occurs in a hot path for scientific computation.  It is technically possible to use a `std::mutex` but the `values` vector can have millions of elements and is accessed many times more than that so a `std::mutex` is too heavy.

Checking the assembly [https://godbolt.org/g/nPE9Dt](https://godbolt.org/g/e5cbX5), it seems to use CAS (with the disclaimer my atomic and assembly knowledge is severely limited so my comments are likely incorrect):

```
  mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
  mov rdi, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx]
  mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx + 8]
  cmp rdi, rax
  jge .LBB0_6
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rsi]
.LBB0_2: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  cmp qword ptr [rcx + 8*rdi], r8
  je .LBB0_3
  inc rdi
  cmp rdi, rax
  jl .LBB0_2
  jmp .LBB0_6
 #### Interesting stuff happens from here onwards
.LBB0_3:
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rdx]             # Load values pointer into register
  mov rax, qword ptr [rcx + 8*rdi]     # Offset to value[i]
.LBB0_4: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movq xmm1, rax                       # Move value into floating point register
  addsd xmm1, xmm0                     # Add function arg to the value from the vector<double>
  movq rdx, xmm1                       # Move result to register
  lock                                 # x86 lock
  cmpxchg qword ptr [rcx + 8*rdi], rdx # Compare exchange on the value in the vector
  jne .LBB0_4                          # If failed, go back to the top and try again
.LBB0_6:
  ret
```

Is this possible to do using C++ atomics?  The examples I've seen only use `std::atomic<double> value{}` and nothing in the context of accessing a value through a pointer.

Comment: Do you want to switch from OpenMP to another paradigm at all? If not, why not stick with OpenMP atomics? Be advised that [mixing `std::atomic` and OpenMP is not straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316118/620382).

Comment: @Zulan I plan on dropping OpenMP completely.  I'm aware of the pitfalls of mixing, which is why I'm asking how to handle the `#pragma omp atomic` without using OpenMP :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use an atomic memory access for non-atomic memory variable in current C++ (see, e.g., here for some explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/38294551/580083). Moreover, C++ threading before C++17 is more about function parallelism than data parallelism. In HPC, I would definitely stick with OpenMP, which is much more established here than C++ threading (where you cannot, e.g., simply parallelize loops etc.).

Comment: Also, note that specialization of `std::atomic` for floating-point types is added in C++2a, which is another reason I wouldn't abandon OpenMP for HPC codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `std::vector<std::atomic<double>>` but you cannot change its size.

The first thing I'd do is get `gsl::span` or write my own variant.  Then `gsl::span<std::atomic<double>>` is a better model for `values` than `std::vector<std::atomic<double>>`.

Once we have done that, simply remove the `#pragma omp atomic` and your code is atomic in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).  In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and before you have to manually implement `+=`.

```
double old = values[i];
while(!values[i].compare_exchange_weak(old, old+value))
{}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/g/yzUjKF).

Clang 5 generates:

```
omp_atomic_add(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<std::atomic<double>, std::allocator<std::atomic<double> > >&, unsigned long, unsigned long, double): # @omp_atomic_add(std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&, std::vector<std::atomic<double>, std::allocator<std::atomic<double> > >&, unsigned long, unsigned long, double)
  mov rax, qword ptr [rdi]
  mov rdi, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx]
  mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 8*rcx + 8]
  cmp rdi, rax
  jge .LBB0_6
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rsi]
.LBB0_2: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  cmp qword ptr [rcx + 8*rdi], r8
  je .LBB0_3
  inc rdi
  cmp rdi, rax
  jl .LBB0_2
  jmp .LBB0_6
.LBB0_3:
  mov rax, qword ptr [rdx]
  mov rax, qword ptr [rax + 8*rdi]
.LBB0_4: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  mov rcx, qword ptr [rdx]
  movq xmm1, rax
  addsd xmm1, xmm0
  movq rsi, xmm1
  lock
  cmpxchg qword ptr [rcx + 8*rdi], rsi
  jne .LBB0_4
.LBB0_6:
  ret
```

which seems identical to my casual glance.

There is a proposal for [`atomic_view`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0019r1.html) that lets you manipulate a non-atomic value through an atomic view.  In general, C++ only lets you operate atomically on atomic data.

Comment: This was just a small example, the actual code lives inside a class and I can't change the underlying storage.  Section 4 of that proposal seems to directly address this problem - thanks for the reference.